# Issues with OSM encoding

Tags: r, openstreetmap, osmosis, encoding

I am having troubles with the encoding of the osm data in R. Here is a reproducible example using the osmar package:

```
osmData <- osmar::get_osm(osmar::center_bbox(23.334360, 42.693180, 100, 100))
osmData$nodes$tags[80:100, ] #the output is not UTF-8
```

I have also downloaded a planet file from https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/. The filename is "bulgaria-latest.osm.bz2".

After unzipping it, installing osmosis, and reading the file with *osmar::get_osm(source = osmsource_osmosis(fileName))* I still have the same issue. The cyrilics letters are not readable.

I am using a 64bit Windows 10 with R version 3.3.3. My default encoding is Bulgarian, but I have also tried English encoding in R with no help.

Any ideas how can I counter this?

Comment: crossposted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215553/issues-with-osm-encoding + https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/57219/issues-with-osm-encoding-in-r

Comment: For OSM data, you need utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Cyrillic letters look perfectly good to me. `Encoding(.)` reports them as UTF-8.

Comment: @Spacedman Did you use osmar package? What is your locale? On mine, in order to see Encoding I have to write *Encoding(as.character(osmData$nodes$tags[80:100, "v"]))* and the results is "unknown"

Comment: I did exactly that and I see a mix of "unknown" and "UTF-8". The "unknowns" are plain text where there's not enough info to work out the encoding. `Sys.getlocale()` values are mostly "en_GB.utf8"

Comment: Ok, I tried this in Linux and it works. Apparently, it is connected to Windows locale. Have not found how to fix this in Windows yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Answering my own question:

I ran the above code in linux and understood that the issue was with the windows locale. The workaround I found was to use iconv with *from* and *to* parameters set to *"UTF-8"*.

```
iconv(osmData$nodes$tags[80:100,3][11], from="UTF-8", to="UTF-8")
```

This works and could be applied to all columns.